# Tracking events and making sense of it

Tags: google-analytics

Lets say I wish to track
User action - game he played - which area he stays - his house number.

If I were to track these event actions in Tabular format, it would look like:
UserId|Game|Area|House|Timestamp so on.
Then I can always run SQL queries if I want to answer few business queries. Like
1. In a given day/week, who is the most active User
2. Which game is most-played?
3. Which area plays most events
4. Which user from which area are the most active

Whats the best way to capture this using Google analytics? Will custom dimensions be useful. Or GA is not suitable for this kind of insight?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the house number is too precise, it would be against GA's ToS.

In GA everything is captured in "hits", you can think of this as one "row" of data.

Let's look at what you wanted to find out:

1. Most Active User? - *This depends on how you determine "Active". Is it the longest Session durations? Tried most games? Most logins? Most sessions? To track a user, you'd need a User ID tracked.*
2. Which game is played the most? - *Again, what is played the most? Longest time in game? Most "start" games? This would require you to know the Game that was played and when someone started playing*
3. Which area is most active? -*This would go back to the definition of active, the region information is needed along with the active definition*
4. Which users are most active in an area? *Same as above, the user would need to be identified and area*

To determine which Custom Dimensions (CDs) you want, let's look at the example data points you want to track and try to [determine the scope](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#processing) and if it already exists as a standard dimension:

- User ID - *this is obviously related to the user, makes sense to be user-scoped*
- Game - *This is a tougher CD. I would think that in a single session, users can play multiple games, thus I'd think you'd want this to be hit-scoped.*
- Area - *GA already provides this based on the ISP*
- Timestamp - *GA already provides time dimensions*

From above, we can determine that you need to create two CDs, one to track User ID, the other to track the Game.

You can also look into using [the userid feature](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en) in GA for cross-device tracking.

Comment: Thanks. Its an internal app which will run in kiosk mode and user enters their data. So no privacy concerns as such. Like an attendance system. So for every punch-in (login) that user makes, would a single hit suffice in capturing the relevant information or multiple event/category/action hits required?

Comment: You’re not allowed to keep personal data in GA.